How to query for aggregated streaks?
My goal is to detect price trends for cryptocurrencies. For that I'm getting OHLC pricing data for multiple currencies vs. multiple quote symbols (e.g. candles for Bitcoin/USD, Bitcoin/EUR, Litecoin/USD etc.). To accomplish calculating trends I use the Supertrend indicator. I have the following 2 tables:
-- This is where price candles AKA OHLC data gets stored. Interval can be '1h', '4h', '1d', etc.
CREATE TABLE ohlc (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('ohlc_id_seq'::regclass) PRIMARY KEY,
    open numeric(65,30) NOT NULL,
    high numeric(65,30) NOT NULL,
    low numeric(65,30) NOT NULL,
    close numeric(65,30) NOT NULL,
    coinid character varying(255) NOT NULL REFERENCES coin(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    closetime timestamp(3) without time zone NOT NULL,
    quotesymbol text NOT NULL,
    interval text NOT NULL
);

-- This is a caching table that gets automatically populated by a stored procedure that runs AFTER every ohlc insert. "trend" can be 'UP' or 'DOWN'.
CREATE TABLE supertrend (
    id integer DEFAULT nextval('supertrend_id_seq'::regclass) PRIMARY KEY,
    coinid character varying(255) NOT NULL REFERENCES coin(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    quotesymbol text NOT NULL,
    date timestamp(3) without time zone NOT NULL,
    trend text NOT NULL,
    interval text NOT NULL
);

Sample data for the supertrend table:



coinid
quotesymbol
date
trend
interval




'bitcoin'
'usd'
'2024-04-18 00:00:00'
'UP'
'1d'


'bitcoin'
'usd'
'2024-04-17 00:00:00'
'UP'
'1d'


'bitcoin'
'usd'
'2024-04-16 00:00:00'
'UP'
'1d'


'bitcoin'
'usd'
'2024-04-15 00:00:00'
'DOWN'
'1d'


'bitcoin'
'eur'
'2024-04-18 00:00:00'
'UP'
'1d'


'bitcoin'
'eur'
'2024-04-17 00:00:00'
'UP'
'1d'


'bitcoin'
'eur'
'2024-04-16 00:00:00'
'DOWN'
'1d'


'bitcoin'
'eur'
'2024-04-15 00:00:00'
'DOWN'
'1d'


'bitcoin'
'cny'
'2024-04-18 00:00:00'
'DOWN'
'1d'


'bitcoin'
'cny'
'2024-04-17 00:00:00'
'UP'
'1d'


'bitcoin'
'cny'
'2024-04-16 00:00:00'
'UP'
'1d'


'bitcoin'
'cny'
'2024-04-15 00:00:00'
'UP'
'1d'


'litecoin'
'usd'
'2024-04-18 00:00:00'
'DOWN'
'1d'


'litecoin'
'usd'
'2024-04-17 00:00:00'
'UP'
'1d'


'litecoin'
'usd'
'2024-04-16 00:00:00'
'DOWN'
'1d'


'litecoin'
'usd'
'2024-04-15 00:00:00'
'DOWN'
'1d'


'bitcoin'
'usd'
'2024-04-18 00:00:00'
'UP'
'4h'


'bitcoin'
'usd'
'2024-04-17 20:00:00'
'UP'
'4h'


'bitcoin'
'usd'
'2024-04-17 16:00:00'
'DOWN'
'4h'



Let's say I want to query for the latest (ORDER BY date DESC) trend for every coinid/quotesymbol with interval = '1d' (1 day). Or in other words I want to WHERE interval = '1d' GROUP BY coinid, quotesymbol Also, I want to know the trend streak, so for how many time periods that trend is already the same.
Given the above example supertrend table data, my result should look like:



coinid
quotesymbol
latest_trend
trend_streak




'bitcoin'
'usd'
'UP'
3


'bitcoin'
'eur'
'UP'
2


'bitcoin'
'cny'
'DOWN'
1


'litecoin'
'usd'
'DOWN'
1



To clarify the above result:
'Bitcoin', 'usd' is 'UP' for 3 periods, because the trend for Bitcoin/USD was up on April 18, April 17 and April 16. And 'DOWN' on April 15, see sample supertrend table.
Additionally, I would like to know the aggregated supertrend over all quotesymbols (via mode function). That result should look like this:



coinid
latest_trend
trend_streak




'bitcoin'
'UP'
2


'litecoin'
'DOWN'
1



To clarify the above result: The latest Bitcoin/USD trend is 'UP, Bitcoin/EUR is 'EUR' is 'UP' and Bitcoin/CNY is 'DOWN'. The mode function takes ('UP', 'UP', 'DOWN') and returns the most frequent occuring value ('UP').
How can I query for this data in an efficient way considering the supertrend table has millions or billions of rows?
I was thinking of a materialized view but the lowest possible intervals for those supertrends are 1 minute and the might be written at distinct times, so that might be too high of a needed refresh rate.
I'm trying to avoid using a separate caching solution like Redis to keep the amount of needed architecture/environments simple, but I guess that could be an option especially for counters.

we can not get your result without knowing the basis where the information come from, even with a bounty nobody can help you

The algorithm is unclear; you'd have to describe it in more detail. How exactly do you end up with these trend_streak numbers? Phrases that are unclear: "trend ... with interval = '1d'" (there are no dates in your sample data), "quotesymbols", "mode function".

@LaurenzAlbe I edited my question to include a sample base table and made some clarifying comments. Hope its clear now, let me know, thanks!

@nbk Just realized I can only tag one person at a time. Same comment as above applies.

You can use ROW_NUMBER to determine the last value, and then use the a GROUP BY to get your count.
then in the next step  you again can use row_number to determine the trend with the highest count.
the window function ROW_NUMBER() does exactly as its name says it gives a row_number to every row. With a window function, you get that you can virtual group together rows and give a row_number to each group, so that you can have multiple 1 in your result set. in our case we want the last row for ever group so we use as order DESC
The LAGwindow function in a group for the previous  value, it is often used like here to compare the current value with its predecessor and detect changes.
more about window function ca be sound in the manual
You can add to the WHERE clause the coinids you want to show.
Like  WHERE rn = 1 AND "coinid" = 'bitcoin'
The second Query is a bit simpler, because first you detect the changes in every "coinid", "quotesymbol" and "tend".
The Window function sum then creates group, as youi are only intereets  in the last, so we care only about the rn =m 1.
Your expected result confused me, but after constructing your the query i saw your error
CREATE TABLE superstreak (
  "coinid" VARCHAR(10),
  "quotesymbol" VARCHAR(5),
  "date" date,
  "trend" VARCHAR(4),
  "interval" VARCHAR(4)
);

INSERT INTO superstreak
  ("coinid", "quotesymbol", "date", "trend", "interval")
VALUES
  ('bitcoin', 'usd', '2024-04-18 00:00:00', 'UP', '1d'),
  ('bitcoin', 'usd', '2024-04-17 00:00:00', 'UP', '1d'),
  ('bitcoin', 'usd', '2024-04-16 00:00:00', 'UP', '1d'),
  ('bitcoin', 'usd', '2024-04-15 00:00:00', 'DOWN', '1d'),
  ('bitcoin', 'eur', '2024-04-18 00:00:00', 'UP', '1d'),
  ('bitcoin', 'eur', '2024-04-17 00:00:00', 'UP', '1d'),
  ('bitcoin', 'eur', '2024-04-16 00:00:00', 'DOWN', '1d'),
  ('bitcoin', 'eur', '2024-04-15 00:00:00', 'DOWN', '1d'),
  ('bitcoin', 'cny', '2024-04-18 00:00:00', 'DOWN', '1d'),
  ('bitcoin', 'cny', '2024-04-17 00:00:00', 'UP', '1d'),
  ('bitcoin', 'cny', '2024-04-16 00:00:00', 'UP', '1d'),
  ('bitcoin', 'cny', '2024-04-15 00:00:00', 'UP', '1d'),
  ('litecoin', 'usd', '2024-04-18 00:00:00', 'DOWN', '1d'),
  ('litecoin', 'usd', '2024-04-17 00:00:00', 'UP', '1d'),
  ('litecoin', 'usd', '2024-04-16 00:00:00', 'DOWN', '1d'),
  ('litecoin', 'usd', '2024-04-15 00:00:00', 'DOWN', '1d'),
  ('bitcoin', 'usd', '2024-04-18 00:00:00', 'UP', '4h'),
  ('bitcoin', 'usd', '2024-04-17 20:00:00', 'UP', '4h'),
  ('bitcoin', 'usd', '2024-04-17 16:00:00', 'DOWN', '4h');

WITH CTE AS (SELECT
  "coinid", "quotesymbol", "trend",
    ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER(PARTITION By "coinid", "quotesymbol"
        ORDER BY "date" DESC       
    ) rn
FROM superstreak
  WHERE "interval" = '1d'),
  CTE2 as (
SELECT  "coinid", "trend" , COUNT(*) trend_streak  
  FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1 
GROUP BY "coinid","trend"),
CTE3 As (SELECT  "coinid", "trend" ,  trend_streak
  ,     ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER(PARTITION By "coinid"
        ORDER BY trend_streak DESC       
    ) rn2
FROM CTE2)
SELECT  "coinid", "trend" ,  trend_streak
  FROM CTE3
  WHERE rn2 = 1




coinid
trend
trend_streak




bitcoin
UP
2


litecoin
DOWN
1



WITH CTE As (SELECT
  "coinid", "quotesymbol", "trend","date",
    CASE WHEN "trend" = lag( "trend")
    OVER(PARTITION By "coinid", "quotesymbol"
        ORDER BY "date" DESC       
    ) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END rn
FROM superstreak
  WHERE "interval" = '1d'),
CTE2 AS (SELECT "coinid", "quotesymbol", "trend"
,SUM( rn)
    OVER(PARTITION By "coinid", "quotesymbol"
        ORDER BY "date" DESC       
    ) rn
FROM CTE)
SELECT
"coinid", "quotesymbol", "trend", COUNT(*) trend_streak
FROM CTE2
WHeRE rn = 1
GROUP BY "coinid", "quotesymbol", "trend"
ORDER BY trend_streak DESC




coinid
quotesymbol
trend
trend_streak




bitcoin
usd
UP
3


bitcoin
eur
UP
2


bitcoin
cny
DOWN
1


litecoin
usd
DOWN
1



fiddle

Sorry, but this is giving the wrong trend streak count and doesn't conform to the two result sets I was giving.
Please check the example result set under "Given the above example supertrend table data, my result should look like:"

I was hard to comprehend, but i now got it, try it lease again

I'm not sure I understand your solution but it seems to match result set #2... How about result set #1 I was asking about? Please elaborate if any part is still unclear

For that you need a eparate solution but o can't figure out how you come to 3 with USD and bitcoin

So Bitcoin/USD is 'UP' for 3 consecutive days, that's why the trend streak for bitcoin/USD is 3 in the first result set. Check the first few rows of the sample data

i added a solution for your first problem and as you see you are  misstaken with your wanted result, what made me wonder

Ok I imported the sample data to my local database and it seems things are working with your solution. However two things:

There is no mention of interval = '1d' in your solution. Where should I plug that to check for that condition?
It would be very handy if you could explain your solution a little more. I understand the CTE's but window function isn't something I ever worked with and they boggle my mind, could you please annotate or explain how they are actually working?


i added the 1d to the first CTE of both queries, so that theresult is more like you wanted it. for window functions you should read the manual https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html  they are common to day to replace dynamic functions in most cases, if still something is unclear  ask

In the last query:
Why does this work? In CTE you are assigning the column rn = 1 if the trend <> previous trend.
And then in CTE2 you are making a SUM of those rn values. In my mind that equates to the sum of rows that are different from each other, not the streak. But clearly the SQL works so I wonder why.
Also in the first query:
I understand CTE, but I'm not semantically following what CTE2 and CTE3 are good for, please elaborate if possible.
Why is there WHERE rn = 1  in CTE2? How is this connected with ROW_NUMBER() in CTE3?

you can not mix window function with group by, you want at the same time the last dsta and the the count, which is not possible, CTE2 has access to all tables in the databse and CTE and for CT§ it is the same it can access the hoe databse and the results of CTE and CTE2. so i crete the data as i need them at the end, for the first query i calcluale in  evere CTE the data that o need, that is why the FROM  clauses are the result of a Result from the prior CTE, the data that you wanted and struggled with can not be calcilated directly from the main table, you need to derive them step by step.

IF you don't understan what the ctes do, you need run With CTE AS () SEL;ECT * FROM CTE and so on till you understan what each step actually do with the main table
